# What are the encodedpath and simplepath properties of a GeoJSON geometry?

Tags: geojson, encode

I have GeoJSON FeatureCollection with an encodedpath and simplepath property instead of a coordinate array.

For example:

```
    "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "encodedpath": "sdecF`noxMq@hBKbAH\\r@l@ZFfAKf@b@",
        "simplepath": "sdecFbnoxM}@hDF\\~DnA"
    }
```

When viewed in QGIS, I can view attributes but no geometry.

I don't see this in the [spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946), but I am guessing it is a newer draft?

What are these properties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The geometries are encoded using Google's [Encoded Polyline Algorithm Format](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylinealgorithm) .

You can show the example linestring e.g. with https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylineutility .

I guess encoding the geometry is not part of the GeoJSON specs.